# Workflow Reference Missing Step After Step Changes

Tags: dynamics-365

When I loaded a modified version my plugin for Microsoft Dynamics 365 all of the steps for the plugin were lots.  Fortunately, we had done this in the Sandbox and not production so we recreated an exact replica of the steps by creating new steps that match those in the production environment.

When we create an Invoice we have a Workflow called "Invoice on Create" that is failing with the error "'Error in plugin execution, Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object., InnerException: '"

Reading into the trace file the step that this is linked to is *PluginName.CRM.Plugins.CascadeStatusChange* and this step has the exact configuration at the one in production.

I have tried to use the Microsoft Profiler tool however when I look at the Workflow it shows that the Workflow has no steps.

[image]

My thought then is that a GUID or other thing connection changed but this does not appear to be in the code. I have disabled and enabled the workflow.  I am not sure what else to do to make this work again.

We are in Dynamics 365 version 9.0.

Any help debugging this or solving this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Here is the link you can debug your custom workflow.  Try to see where it fails http://alagunellaikumar.blogspot.com/2015/10/debug-custom-workflow-in-crm.html?m=1

Comment: When I look at the workflow in the Profiler there are no steps listed so I cannot run the Profiler to debug.  I have edited the original question to include so I can include a screenshot.

Comment: Are you missing a pre or post Image registration against the plugin step? If not I would start by reviewing the plugin code, and check for cases where you are not null checking properties retrieved from CRM before accessing them. This is just as likely a data integrity issue as a plugin registration issue.

Comment: @ZachMast thank you for your comment. I have checked and all of the steps and images are the same. I have also put the code back to the same state it was before.  Is it possible that when I lost the steps and then recreated them that since they have different IDs they no longer match in some way? I edited and saved the Workflow but this did not change anything. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks, Josh

Comment: There should be no issue with re-creating the registration steps. You will probably need to add logging statements to your plugin to find out exactly where the failure is.